# How do I iterate through verifying different texts on a page in Robot Framework?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I've got a functioning Robot Framework test that checks for different texts on a page. It's pretty basic. Scans the page for a specific string, then logs a PASS/FAIL if the string is found. Here's my code.

```
Test Keyword
    ${p1}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element   xpath=//*[contains(text(), "A")]
    Run Keyword If  ${p1}  Log To Console  "(A) Present"  ELSE  Log To Console  "(A) Not Present"

    ${p2}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element   xpath=//*[contains(text(), "B")]
    Run Keyword If  ${p2}  Log To Console  "(B) Present"  ELSE  Log To Console  "(B) Not Present"

    ${p3}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element   xpath=//*[contains(text(), "C")]
    Run Keyword If  ${p3}  Log To Console  "(C) Present"  ELSE  Log To Console  "(C) Not Present"
```

This runs perfectly fine, but I'm having trouble making this into a list. Or maybe an array? I'm not sure.

Do I make the xpaths variables inside of the list? Would I make the Run Keyword If statements their own keyword and then just pass those? I'm not sure. Please let me know where I'm going wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in the sample is a repetition of the same code with only one variable - and that is always a good candidate for a loop. This way you'll just pass a different value, doing the same checks.

```
FOR    ${a}    IN    A    B    C

    ${p}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Page Should Contain Element   xpath=//*[contains(text(), "${a}")]
    IF  ${p}  Log To Console  "(${a}) Present"  ELSE  Log To Console  "(${a}) Not Present"

END
```

If the values you're checking are more (or dynamic) and it's not convenient to list them as the looped over, you could put them in a list, and iterate over it:

```
${values}=    Create List   A    B    C
FOR    ${a}    IN    @{values}
# the same code follows here
```